# How to draw a path from source to destination on map in Flutter?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart, location

How to draw a path and show the direction in the flutter map. I'm using google_map_flutter API but I didn't find any possible way to draw a path.

I've also tried a map_view plugin but can't get the possible solution

```
 GoogleMap(
       markers: _markers,
       mapType: MapType.normal,
       initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
           target: latLng,
            zoom: 14.4746,
       ),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
   ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: _goToTheLake,
    label: Text('To the lake!'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
  ),

    Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
       controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng( LatLng(20.008751, 
        73.780037)));
       }
```

Comment: path means polyline ?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/Polyline-class.html

Comment: hey visit this link : https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/08/flutter-how-can-draw-route-on-google.html